# Android tap limiter

Tags: android, tap

I am making a simple side scrolling app for android, where the user has to dodge obstacles that get in there way, currently the user taps the screen to jump and this is picked up by the `onTouchEvent()` method, the issue is if the user repeatedly taps the screen the character jumps up and down and then repeats this for the number of times the user has tapped, what I won't to do is make it so that the app will only accept the first of the users taps. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

When you read a tap, set a flag that shows a tap response (jump) is in progress.  While the flag condition is true, accept tap events and discard them.  When you are ready for another jump, clear the flag.  Simplest way is probably to store the system clock time and just know the duration of a jump.  But you could use some other criterion as well, like for example reaching the end of a jump animation.

Comment: i've tried that but it doesn't seem to work, the flag gets set to one when the jump starts and set to zero when it ends but the issue still purists.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a handled flag until the full event has fired, then allow for input again.

ie.

```
bool beingHandled = false;
onTouch(){
  if (beingHandled)
    return;
  beingHandled = true;
  //code  .... ///
  beingHandled = false;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a static variable in the onTouchEvent() method that keeps track of the last press, and only calls a characterJump() function if enough time has passed. You may even use a couple of variables... time since last characterJump() call as well as time since last touch event, to allow a jump after several presses if they continue